# Apache Rewrite Regex Trouble

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Struggling with a rewrite rule, think it is probably just a bit of incorrect syntax.

I have a URL like this:

http://mydomain.org/foo-bar/from2012-10-29/to2012-11-02/page2/

.htaccess is located within foo-bar/

My rules:

```
# if uri contains dates and page:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "from.*to.*page" [NC]
RewriteRule ^from((19|20|21)\d\d-(0[0-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))/to((19|20|21)\d\d-(0[0-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))/page([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?from=$1&to=$2&p=$3 [NC,L]
```

As you can (hopefully) see, I am trying to translate this:

```
http://mydomain.org/foo-bar/from2012-10-29/to2012-11-02/page2/
```

into this:

```
http://mydomain.org/foo-bar/index.php?$from=2012-10-29&$to=2012-11-02&$p=2
```

But the variable values I am getting are not as I expect. I am getting the following values

```
p= 10
from= 2012-10-29
to= 20
```

Hope someone can point out the obvious for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Re-count your capturing groups. The first group `$1` has the full `from` value, but the second one `$2` (which you're assuming is `to`) has just the century from the `from` value. It looks like the group you want for `to` is `$5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your regex.

Try this code:

```
RewriteRule ^from([^/]+)/to([^/]+)/page([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?from=$1&to=$2&p=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: This looks nice and simple. Could you explain the syntax a little please? Does it only accept properly formatted dates? YYYY-MM-DD  Thanks you.

Comment: `[^/]+)` matches text until next `/` is found so this doesn't require any particular date format like `YYYY-MM-DD` etc. Anything between `from` and `/` is captured in `$1` where anything between `to` and next `/` is captured as `$2` etc.