# InfiniteScroll and Apache Rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, infinite-scroll

I'm confused (again). I am making use of Paul Irish's infinitescroll. I am also making use of apache rewrite in .htaccess.

So I have a URL like this:

```
http://mydomain.org/foo/from2012-10-29/to2012-11-02/
```

My .htaccess rules (which sit in foo/) interpret it thus:

```
# if uri contains ONLY dates :
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /from(.+)to(.+)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^from([^/]+)/to([^/]+)/$ index.php?from=$1&to=$2 [NC,L]

# if uri contains dates and page:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "from.*to.*page" [NC]
RewriteRule ^from([^/]+)/to([^/]+)/page([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?from=$1&to=$2&p=$3 [NC,L]
```

This kind of works as page2's worth of images are added to the screen when I scroll down...but if I continue to scroll down, page2 gets hit again... and again... It just keeps adding page2 images, not moving on to page3.

But this does not happen if I remove the dates from the URL and just use:

```
http://mydomain.org/foo/
```

Related htaccess rules:

```
# if uri contains ONLY page* at the end:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /?page(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^page([0-9]+)/$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

This rule only kicks in once I scroll down and hit the first page2 link... but it does then go on to page3, page4 etc. and then stops when it should.

So what am I doing wrong when including dates?

Thanks in advance.

Mildly related:
[Apache Rewrite Regex Trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638096/apache-rewrite-regex-trouble?noredirect=1#comment29157136_19638096)

Comment: What debug measures have you taken so far?

Comment: Well, because the infinitescroll works using jQuery, i.e. not actually going to a new url, I am not sure how to debug. I see the jQuery calls in console (Chrome) so I see it calling the 'page2' url over and over...I am not an expert at all, so I am struggling to see why one of the above methods work whilst the other only half works.